# Why Laravel project website response is over 10 seconds long on artisan localhost only?

Tags: laravel, laravel-5, laravel-5.4

When I work with my local version of project then every action taken on website needs around 10 seconds long response. It's so frustraiting. And it hapens only on my PC. How can I prevent this action?? Downloading project from VCS to new folder helps for short time. I have Windows 10, Laravel 5.4, PHP 7.0.15. Commands 
    `php artisan cache:clear`
and 
    `php artisan optimize` 
are not helping. Please, can anyone help?

Comment: no xdebug, `APP_DEBUG = false`, disabled laravel debugbar

Answer (score 0):

Do you use xdebug? It can slow down application.

Also check your laravel debug option in .env file, it should be:

```
APP_DEBUG=false
```

Comment: Thank's for answer but this is not it.

Answer (score 0):

That was laravel.log. I deleted it and everything seems to be ok. The file had 56MB of logs. Now i have to find out how to stop logging or create new log file every 2MB.